# Configure iPhone settings programmatically

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

I have been developing an app where I need to configure the IPhone settings programmatically like SMS, MMS, Voice and Data. Over settings page I need to set the limits for SMS, MMS, Voice & Data, so that user cannot use it more than that.

The main thing is to set the limits for all of above; I googled a lot and didn't find any kind of help.

Is it possible to do such thing in iPhone? How can I do it by Private API or by IPhoneSDK? If it is through private API then please suggest me the name of that API or by the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SDK cannot do this.  If this is possible, it will have to be through private API (which means you'll be limited to Cydia and jailbroken iPhones for distribution).

Comment: Thanks for reply......But as I had already mentioned. I need it to do anyhow.So can you suggest me the Private API for this!!!